# Why doesn't Oracle ODAC drivers adhere to proper versioning?

Tags: oracle, versioning, odac

Recently when I had to look into some Oracle ODAC drivers something piqued my interest.
I observed that the Oracle ODAC driver for Oracle 11g was: 2.121.2.0.
The version of the Oracle 12.2C ODAC driver is 12.2.0.1.0.

It strikes me as odd that Oracle suddenly seems to jump 10 major versions. Personally I think this is because they want the version to be equal to the oracle version itself (12.2).

But I still find the versioning weird, and it looks to me like they don't follow the generally accepted versioning rules, although being a major player in the software business.

Versioning as I've learned it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning

Does anyone have an explanation to what seems to be the weird versioning behavior of Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

In the past Oracle changed their version numbering several times (other companies do the same, remember the different versions on MS-Windows). I assume this is mainly driven by marketing reasons.

ODAC version 2.121.2.0 means:

```
2.121.2.0
2 -> .NET Framework version (1.x, 2.x, or 4.x)
     Version 1.x was available up to Oracle 11.1
  121 -> This matches to the Oracle release 12.1
      2.0 -> Release/revision of the ODAC driver 
             Not used anymore, in Oracle 18 or newer always `0.0`
```